# Getting street number from Places API

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api, google-places

I'm using the Google Places API to make entering destinations easy. Ideally, I would like the user to be able to start entering the semantic name (e.g. Stanford University) and have Places API autosuggest an option. I am using results returned by the Geocoder to get the structured place data. However, I notice that if I enter in a query for "Stanford University", the returned geocoded result does not contain a key for street_number. Does anyone know how you can use Places API to geocode a place into a geocode result that includes a street_number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I lookup [Stanford University with the places service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-placeid-finder), it returns the `place_id` `ChIJneqLZyq7j4ARf2j8RBrwzSk`.  A `getDetails` request with that `place_id` returns an address components array with an entry with type `street_number`.

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/29gm7vLk/3/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;
var infowiandow;
var service;
var data_id;
var count = 1;
var request;
var placeIDs = [];

function initialize() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(19.12455, 72.929158),
        zoom: 11
    });
    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var errorCnt = 0;
    var successCnt = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

        placeIDs[i] = data[i]['place_id'];


        infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

        service.getDetails({
            placeId: placeIDs[i]
        }, function (place, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                successCnt += 1;
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: place.geometry.location,
                    title: place.name
                });
                for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
                    for (var j = 0; j < place.address_components[i].types.length; j++) {
                        if (place.address_components[i].types[j] == "street_number") {
                            document.getElementById('info').innerHTML += "street_number:" + place.address_components[i].long_name + "<br>";
                        }
                    }
                }
                console.log(place);
                bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                    infowindow.setContent(place.name + "<br>" + place.types + "<br><a href='" + place.url + "'>url</a>");
                    infowindow.open(map, this);
                });
                document.getElementById('success').innerHTML += "placename=" + place.name + " successCnt=" + successCnt + "<br>";

                map.fitBounds(bounds);
            } else {
                document.getElementById('info').innerHTML += "[" + errorCnt + "] status=" + status + " successCnt=" + successCnt + "<br>";
                errorCnt += 1;
            }
        });
    }
    /* }); */
}
var data = [{
    place_id: "ChIJneqLZyq7j4ARf2j8RBrwzSk"
}];


google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html, body, #map-canvas {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>
<div id="success"></div>
<div id="info"></div>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
 <h4 id="place_id"></h4>
```

Comment: This doesn't show which service you used to look up the place name to get the place_id that you use in your example.

Comment: updated: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-placeid-finder

Comment: Some of the placeId returned by that service do not return a street number even though the place does have a street address. See ChIJd9C2K7xw44kRfuMgxDV7L8k for an example.